# Replacing certain containers inside a cloned "div" in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to replace the contents of a selected "div" element, and append it to the parent control. So far I am able to clone and append it to the parent, but I want to know how I can replace certain tags inside.

to be specific here is the jquery i use to clone the target control

```
var x =  $(parent).children('div[class="answer"]:first').children('div[class="ansitem"]:first').clone();
```

the html content inside the clone div is like this :

```
<div id="ansthumb_anstext_anscontrols">
    <div id="image" class="ansthumb">
        replace 1
    </div>

<div id="atext" class="anstext">
    <p class="atext_para">
        <span id="mainwrapper_QRep_ARep_0_UName_0" style="color: rgb(51, 102, 255); font-weight: bold;">Replace 2 </span>
        Replace 3
    </p>

    <p id="answercontrols">
        <input name="ctl00$mainwrapper$QRep$ctl01$ARep$ctl01$AnsID" id="mainwrapper_QRep_ARep_0_AnsID_0" value='replace 4' type="hidden">
        <a id="mainwrapper_QRep_ARep_0_Like_0" title="Like this answer" href="#">Like</a>
        <a id="mainwrapper_QRep_ARep_0_Report_0" title="Report question" href="#">Report</a>
        <span id="mainwrapper_QRep_ARep_0_lblDatetime_0" class="date">  replace 5 </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

here i have marked all the areas I want to be replaced. The id's of the above div elements are named as such because it is generated within a repeater control.

I have gone through the jquery API and this function seems to be the thing I should be using as far as i understand.

replaceWith(content)

but the drawback of this way is i have to dump  the entire html on to a string variable and include replacement text wherever needed. I think it is not the best way, and may be something like selecting particular tags and changing data would be the way to do it. Any help appreicated guys!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `.html()` and a couple other jQuery functions and use the surrounding elements as your selectors.

For example

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
     $("#image").html("YourData1"); //replace 1

     var secondSpan = $("#mainwrapper_QRep_ARep_0_UName_0");
     $(secondSpan).html("YourData2"); //replace 2
     $(secondSpan).after("YourData3"); //replace 3

     $("#mainwrapper_QRep_ARep_0_AnsID_0").attr("value", "YourData4"); //replace 4

     $("#mainwrapper_QRep_ARep_0_lblDatetime_0").html("YourData5"); //replace 5

 </script>
```

Since these ids are defined by .NET, you can get the ClientID of the .NET control.

For example:

```
var secondSpan = $("#<%= UName.ClientID %>");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would the .after call you are using for replace 3 not just append the new text rather than replacing whatever was there before?

Comment: If you look at his example, replace 3 is wrapped in the <p> tag but not the <span> where replace 2 is.  So yes, it'll append "YourData3".

Comment: OH.  I understand.  All the "replace" literal texts should be removed from the original HTML, since they don't actually matter.